# Difference between MP and SP (or is it Core) in CUDA parallelism?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

### So, after reading some very useful posts, I came to the conclusion that,

1. Each Grid of Blocks executes on a single device. 
   (e.g Device has 9 MP)
2. Each Block of Threads executes on a single MultiProcessor.
   (e.g 1 MP has 8 SP/Cores).
3. Each Group of Threads (called warps) executes on a SP/Core.

Now, if I assume that

1. I have a total of 72 Cores (9*8) ,
2. I call kernel with 9 blocks and 8 threads,total 72 threads.
3. All the 72 threads will run in parallel ?

However, If I call more than that, then they will not run in parallel ?

Comment: Only a warp ever runs truly in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Each Grid of Blocks executes on a single device. (e.g Device has 9 MP)
```

Yes!

```
Each Block of Threads executes on a single MultiProcessor. (e.g 1 MP has 8 SP/Cores).
```

Yes!

```
Each Group of Threads (called warps) executes on a SP/Core.
```

No! Typically a warp (32 threads on all current hardware) is distributed amongst the cores.

```
Now, if I assume that

I have a total of 72 Cores (9*8) ,
I call kernel with 9 blocks and 8 threads,total 72 threads.
All the 72 threads will run in parallel ?
```

Yes! But it won't be very fast...

```
However, If I call more than that, then they will not run in parallel ?
```

They will run in parallel. A GPU achieves good performance via over-subscription. A core cannot complete an instruction in one cycle, and takes many cycles to return (this is known as `latency`). By having more threads than cores you can issue another instruction in the gap between the instruction being started, and it executing. This is the only way you can get peak performance out of a GPU - by having many threads per core - and is fundamental to GPU programming. There are limits on how many threads an SM can have on it, but typically you want as many as possible, several times as many threads as you have cores.

From a programmers point of view all threads within a grid run in parallel. From a hardware point of view every SM runs in parallel with every other SM. Each SM can have multiple warps with instructions executing on each cycle. Each instruction is executed in parallel across the cores of a SM. Each core can have many operations in its pipeline.

The subtle difference between the programmer's point of view and the hardware's point of view, is that there are resource based dependencies in the hardware. These dependancies aren't visible to the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

> Each Grid of Blocks executes on a single device. (e.g Device has 9 MP)

Correct.

> Each Block of Threads executes on a single MultiProcessor. (e.g 1 MP
>   has 8 SP/Cores).

Thread blocks are separately scheduled onto SMs, and threads within a given block are executed by the same SM.

> Each Block of Threads executes on a single MultiProcessor. (e.g 1 MP
>   has 8 SP/Cores).

Right. A thread block executes on one multiprocessor, they don't migrate to another SM during the kernel execution.

> If I call more than that , they will not run in parallel?

The short answer is no. Only a warp ever truly runs in parallel (as @ebarr said).

The long answer is that a warp is mapped onto an SM (one thread by SP) and all the 32 threads run in parallel in the SM. If, for some reason, one of the threads needs to perform a long latency operation this will cause the rest of the threads (and the other warps in the queue of the SM) to be idle. To solve that, CUDA uses fast context switches between warps.

So that, there is parallelism at thread level (within a warp) and at warp level (different SM are running one warp at a given moment).

**What happens if you launch more threads than 72?** Launching more that 72 threads is the purpose of CUDA. As I said before, the way of hiding operators latency is by context switches, i.e. launching tons of threads.

Thread blocks will be divided into warps and these warps will be scheduled and queued on SMs and executed in an *unknown* order.